# ASP.Net C# ASPNETDB.mdb with SQL 2008 R2 Developers and SQL Express 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, sql-server-2008-r2, membership-provider

I have installed instances of both SQL Express and SQL Developers edition.  I have installed my customer DB on SQL Developers Edtion using LINQ to Entities.  I migrated tfro SQL Express as I was having a problem with SQL Express and a n-tier application(3 projects).

I am ready to add in my membership provider (both membership and role provider) for my application but I want to be sure it is created using SQL Developers Edition.  **How do I create the provider?**

Also, being such a newbie, I need help in creating the CONNECTION STRING for my ASPNETDB.mdb database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is a nice video you can reference as well which can explain how to create your membership provider hope this helps http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider if you are looking to do something with Users/Groups there are some scripts that have to be run against the ASPNETDB.mdb I did this 8 months ago but wish i had those storedprocedures to paste for you to run.. setting it up is fairly easy too..

Comment: Take a look at this link as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx is any of this helping you..??

Comment: I'm at work right now and this is a personal project -- hope to work on it tonight.  If it takes some time to accomplish, as it appears, it may have to wait for the weekend. Many THANKS!

Comment: it doesn't take that much time actually.. if you have any issues please feel free to msg back here and I am sure that someone or myself would be more than happy to help you out..

Comment: HI DJ ... I just looked at the tutorial on creating a custom membership provider, but I'm really uncertain about some of the steps (I'm such a newbie!)  Would you be willing to schedule a time to chat?  If so, when might you be available this weekend?

Comment: Would love to schedule a time to chat.. do you use facebook or yahoo chat..?

Comment: Sorry in being so long to get back to you, been ill.  I use Facebook.  What time(s) are good for you ... I'm on Central Standard Time (US)

Comment: I am Central Standard Time too.. You're in Wisconsin I use to live in Chicago.. and in Texas now so we are on he same timezone.. I am at work.. here is my email mrcaston yahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use a Trusted Connection use something like this.. I would recommend porting these values to a web.config or app.config file too
if I were in a .config file it would look something like this

```
<appSettings>
<add key="strConnectionString" value="Data Source=YourDomain\ServerName;
    Initial Catalog=yourDatabaseNameP;User ID=YourUser;Trusted_Connection=yes"/>
</appSettings>

// .NET DataProvider -- Trusted Connection  

using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Data Source=ServerName;" + 
              "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" + 
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"; 
conn.Open();
```

or

```
// .NET DataProvider -- Standard Connection  

using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Data Source=ServerName;" + 
              "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" + 
              "User id=UserName;" + 
              "Password=Secret;"; //change to fit your case
conn.Open();
```